# Why do services generate multiple 2FA backup codes?

Tags: account-security, multi-factor, backup

In case you lose access to your two-factor authentication (2FA) codes, you are only required to enter one of the backup codes. So why do services like Google generate multiple codes if it doesn't increase and maybe even decrease security or user experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup codes are usually one-time use only, giving you enough fallback options for multiple occurrences of their usage. These include:

- losing the device;
- switching to another device;
- disabling 2FA for whatever reason.

As far as I am aware this is for convenience reasons. There is next to no loss in case of a security breach as the backup codes are (hopefully) stored securely by analogue means. requesting a 2FA reset should hardly allow surface for brute-forcing the codes, and even if that was the case it would barely make a difference if there are 10 or merely 1 valid codes.

Comment: This makes sense. I thought backup codes automatically regenerate after one is used, but this is not the case.

Comment: No, they don't get regenerated after use. You have to manually trigger a regenerate.